# Shapefile data not displaying on MapInfo workspace?

Tags: shapefile, mapinfo

I have a number of shapefiles created from ARCMap and would like it displayed in MapInfo (version 10.5) but the polygon is not displayed on the work space.

I can view my attributes table by browse table and I can select a polygon although I cannot view it (the image below show it is selected). I can also see the node by setting show node in layer properties.

Could anyone tell me what I missed?

[image]

Comment: Try saving the shapefile as a MapInfo TAB file and see if the geometry comes through. It is possible for a shapefile to not have any geometry.  It's also possible to have corrupt data.  How have you loaded the shapefile?  File/Open?  Or Open Universal Data?

Comment: You have a theme on the layer, could that be set to display "unknown" values invisible?