# Can not open shapefiles from QGIS 2.18 in MapInfo 16.0, projection was missing

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, mapinfo, qgis-2, tab

I am working with QGIS 2.18 where I do have several shapefiles in EPSG 4326 and encoded in ISO 8859-1, see image below.

[image: Shapefiles_in_QGIS]

I can check their geometry state for instance with [Geometry Validator](https://github.com/peetw/GeometryValidator) or [Check Geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html) plugins. As the result, I do not have any vital issues, and it basically means that *the geometry* itself *is not missing*. See the output below.

[image: Geometry_Validator_Output]

But when I open both of them in MapInfo Pro 16.0 I can't see any of them. I did it through the following command (see the image below)

> Home > Open > Relation

[image: Shapefiles_in_MapInfo]

Then MapInfo asks me to save my shapefiles with `.tab` extension. And I proceed with it.

And after I can not see my shapefiles in MapInfo. Check the following image.

[image: Problem_no_visualization_in_MapInfo]

---

**In QGIS**

I tried to `Save As...` MapInfo TAB which did not solve the issue.

I deployed `ogr2ogr` from the GDAL/OGR Processing Toolbox, where I used `[OGR] Conversion > Convert format`. However, the output still does not want to show up in MapInfo.

Moreover, I changed the encoding between System, UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1, nothing helps.

I have tried to `Save As...` GML file, also does not help.

---

**In MapInfo**

I tried "Universal Translator". Nevertheless, I do not have an option to chose `.shp` format from the "FME Reader Galarie" list, but there are some other options, for instance `.gml`, `.kml`, `.gdb`, `.mdb` etc.

I have also tried with MapInfo Professional 12.5, and MapInfo Pro 15 - nothing.

---

**So, my Question is**: What could be actually the problem? Geometry? Coordinate System? Original data (which was created from .dxf)? Wrong conversion from QGIS into MapInfo? Corrupt data? Wrong execution of the data input in MapInfo?

I have tried several similar topics but they do not transparently respond to my issue.

- [Shapefile data not displaying on MapInfo workspace?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140805/shapefile-data-not-displaying-on-mapinfo-workspace)
- [Tool for converting .shp file to .tab file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/tool-for-converting-shp-file-to-tab-file?rq=1)
- [QGIS from SHP to TAB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214835/qgis-from-shp-to-tab)
- [How to import a shapefile (.shp) into MapInfo Pro](http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CeblCAC&popup=false&lang=en_US)

Comment: Are there any rows when you browse the tables (F2)? Did you try "View Entire Layer"?

Comment: Yes, I do have rows in the attribute table, but I do not see them in the workspace

Comment: And when you select one and press Ctrl+A?

Comment: It selects all other rows.

Comment: That should have been "Query ­→ Find Selection → In All Windows".

Comment: Did you try "Universal Translator" in MapInfo? you can load it in Tools>Tool Manager>Universal Translator (My MapInfo version is quite old it might have changed)

Comment: Thanks [@Pescariz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/55795/pescariz), but it is not possible. In "Universal Translator" I do not have an option to chose `.shp` format from the "FME Reader Galarie" list, but there are some options with `.gdb`, `.mdb`. Therefore, I will try to convert my shapefiles into one of those formats.

Comment: Please provide a small sample of the original SHP. The issue is unlikely to be QGIS or MapInfo, but the structure or form of the data themselves.

Comment: [@Ralph Tee](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84537/ralph-tee), I will try if it does not exceed my company policy and the copyrights of the data.

Comment: Create a simple shapefile, making sure the topology is correct, like for example only one polygon with a few attributes. Export this file from QGIS to MapInfo and see what happens and also try all other conversion options you mentioned. This way you know that your converters are working and you can eliminate one unknown in your problem. Also, use the default encoding, and change one thing at a time to see where the process fails.

Comment: [@Ralph Tee](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84537/ralph-tee), basically because of you I have found the solution. See the update of my question. Therefore, I would like to award you the bounty, if you do not mind. However, I still have some questions, see above. I would be glad if you can answer them, if not, just put your comment as a full answer! Thanks!

Comment: @Taras. You actually have one Duek_Flachen.SHP and one Duek_Flachen.SHP.XML. Same as all other SHPs and XMLs. Check your Windows Explorer setting (ie Menu->View->Options->View->Files and Folders->Hide extensions for known file type). And, (2) as for your other questions - put them as separate, and I'm sure many good folks here (me included) would be more than happy to answer them.

Comment: Dear [@Ralph Tee](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84537/ralph-tee), I still would like to award you with bounty points, because your small but precise hint saved me a lot of time. So I would be really glad if you can slightly describe the situation with the data structure/form, of course, if you have time for that. On the other hand, as you suggested, preparing a new question looks for me a bit complicated because people have to dig in this issue as well. And moreover, I have not investigated the issue with several shp files for one layer yet, maybe the answer already exists for that. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conclusion: Always check the data input.**

I have recently doublechecked the data state and structure as was suggested by [@Ralph Tee](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84537/ralph-tee) and realized that several of my **shapefiles are missing the projection files `.prj`**, see image below.

It was my fault that I asked my initial question based on the already processed data, without examining the raw input.

[image: Example_of_missing_prj_files]

Luckily one of the origin shapefiles included the `.prj` file, where it says

> PROJCS["ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_33N",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

So, it is basically EPSG:25833 which could be easily chosen for the rest of shapefiles. Afterwards, the reprojection process is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your layer in another shapefile with selection of geometry type : 'Polygon'?

Or if you save your layer in MapInfo MIF/MID (not MapInfo TAB...) to import data with MapInfo?